# EXERCISE 1.2.ii (ii) of "CATEGORY THEORY IN CONTEXT"

Tags: category-theory

How to solve the EXERCISE 1.2.ii (ii) of Riehl's "CATEGORY THEORY IN CONTEXT"?

EXERCISE 1.2.ii (ii) is the following.

> A morphism $f: x \to y$ is a split epimorphism in a category $C$ if and only if for all $c \in C$, post-composition $f_{*}: C(c, x) \to C(c, y)$ defines a surjective function.
> Argue by duality that $f$ is a split monomorphism if and only if for all $c \in C$, pre-composition $f^{*}: C(y, c) \to C(x, c)$ is a surjective function.

Now I can show that a morphism $f: x \to y$ is a split epimorphism in a category $C$ if and only if for all $c \in C$, post-composition $f_{*}: C(c, x) \to C(c, y)$ defines a surjective function.

And without the arguement by duality I can show that $f$ is a split monomorphism if and only if for all $c \in C$, pre-composition $f^{*}: C(y, c) \to C(x, c)$ is a surjective function.

But I cannot show the above statement using the arguement by duality.

Comment: Simply apply the generic statement you proved to the opposite category $C^{op}$.

Comment: If you've been able to prove both parts, the proofs should be quite similar, and the source of this similiarity is precisely the duality.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I could show the statement in the way Berci answered.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the following statement in $C^{op}$ holds. The statement in $C^{op}$ is equivalent to the statement in $C$. Therefore the statement in $C$ holds.

### statement in $C^{op}$

$f^{op}: x \to y$ is a split epimorphism in $C^{op}$ if and only if for all $c \in C^{op}$, post-composition $f_{*}: C^{op}(c, x) \to C^{op}(c, y)$ defines a surjective function.

### statement in $C$

$f: y \to x$ is a split monomorphism in $C$ if and only if for all $c \in C$, pre-composition $f^{*}: C(x, c) \to C(y, c)$ defines a surjective function.